# Flutter post to nodejs API with image file and string field as json string

Tags: dart, flutter

Hoping to find an example of using Flutter to send a form post to Node.js and pass a string that is JSON and an image file.

I have been trying `http.MultipartRequest`, but the node service does not get anything in files or fields.

Not sure what I am doing wrong, so any guidance would be great.

```
var _url = Uri.parse('http://$baseurl/chat/messages/send');

var request = new http.MultipartRequest('POST', _url);
request.fields['json'] = json;
request.files.add(new http.MultipartFile.fromString(widget.mychat.msgkey, myimagefile.path));
```

Am I missing an easier way?  Tried to BASE64 encode the image and add as a string in JSON, but the server keeps crashing even after I changed the amount of client request nginx would allow.  I need it to work for an image or video sent from mobile.

Comment: Did you search for Dart? There isn't anything special about Flutter, except that Dart web answer might not work, but Flutter makes HTTP requests the same as Dart console or server apps do.

Comment: Any information about the server crash? Error output, stack trace, ...?

Comment: I got the current example from dart, just hoped there may be someone doing flutter and trying the same thing.

Comment: Once I got it to push to the server, continued to get a epipe error from node and it would not store it in DB.

Comment: Can you please post the concrete error message?

Comment: @Gunter  Actually, flutter has a few specific stuff. `createHttpClient` is one of them

Comment: @Darky what does it do? `HttpClient` from `dart:io` worked fine for me so far.

Comment: It does. But you're supposed to use the client from `createHttpClient` because it helps for testing purpose. And this changes a few methods (get has only one parameter instead of 3 for example).

Comment: @Darky Thanks, just found it on https://flutter.io/networking/

Comment: When I try base64.encode of image and pass it in JSON, all works but my nodejs bombs with this: throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: write EPIPE
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:870:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:893:20)
    at WriteWrap.afterWrite (net.js:763:14)

Comment: @Darky do you have an example of using createHttpClient to post multipart form with image file?  I use it alot for all my json posts and gets of data, but could not find a way to get the image and multipart to work.  Thanks

Comment: @Robert Sadly no. I've only used firebase with flutter.

Comment: Does anyone have an example of decoding back into the imagefile from the BASE64.encoded?  I got the encoded file to upload and go into mysql as JSON, it was a mysql error.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the exact same issue. The problem is not with MultipartRequest but the nodejs server.
The body-parser module you are using in the nodejs API can not handle multipart/form-data , it can only handle x-www-form-urlencoded

The solution is : You have to use module like **multer** in your nodejs API

```
const multer  = require('multer')
let upload  = multer({ storage: multer.memoryStorage() });

router.route('/signup').post(upload.single('avatar'),function (req, res) {
    console.log('signup page');
    console.log(req.file);
    console.log(req.body);
    //res.status(200).json({"success": "Signup page"});
    res.end('hello world');
});
```

Found a nice solution here http://derpturkey.com/node-multipart-form-data-explained/